Can I use a WIFI FEM with a 2.4GHz FSK transceiver?
I'm using a SX1280 which has FSK modulation. I need to amplify the signal to almost 30dBm. The problem is that my last FEM has been discontinued and I need to find another. For 2.4 GHz there are a lot of amplifier, but almost all are specialized in WIFI. Can I still use these FEMs?

Have you optimized the gain of your antennae?

The main problem is that this SX1280 goes in a rocket, so I cannot increase too much the antenna gain because it is not easy to track it.

30dBm is rather high, on the verge of the FCC limit for 2.4GHz in fact. I think that's probably why the question with the antenna came up, to make sure you can accurately send nothing higher than 30dBm. The SX1280 FEM you have mentioned isn't meant to contain IEEE standards for WiFi so I don't think you can use WiFi related applications. LoRa devices are meant to do long distance and handle small amounts of information (kilobytes or even less). WiFi is not long range at all.

When I supported Black Brandt rockets at the NRC range in Churchill with a large helix high gain antenna, all I had to do was just point up in the general direction with 15 dB gain. Meanwhile, main telemetry had quad helix servo-tracking antennae.  But for the rocket, I had the vacuum of space with an inertial despun flat braided antenna stretched out with the nose cone ejected.  You would need an axial patch or dual antenna  The main issue is which direct is best for a non-isotropic antenna?  Do you have access to an ISM band at 928 MHz or lower?
